# How to make selectInput choices overlay dq_accordion?

Tags: r, shiny

In the following shiny app, the choices in `selectInput` are hidden by `dq_accordion`.

```
library(shiny)
library(dqshiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dq_accordion(
      id = "foo",
      titles = list(
        "Something",
        "Something else"
      ),

      contents = tagList(
        tagList(
          selectInput("test", 
                      "Test", 
                      choices = names(mtcars))
        ),
        tagList(
          checkboxInput('foo2', "foo2")
        )
      )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I make the choices overlay `dq_accordion` when the user clicks on `selectInput`?

I tried to use the CSS code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54933844/11598948) but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".selectize-control {position: static;}"))
  ),
  ......
```